# Javascript Object : instance variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, socket.io, scope

I wonder if someone can help me. Coming from a Java, C++ background I am trying to write a neat OO implementation in Javascript. I am using the following pattern with Socket.io.

In the listen function, the instance variables are properly defined on the first alert. The x instance variable goes out of scope in the socket.on event listener and both instance variables go out of scope in the JQuery $.each

Can someone explain what is going on here ?

```
var Player = (function () {

this.x  = "";

//Constructor
var Player = function() {
    // connect to the server
    this.x = "somevalue";
    this.socket  = io.connect();

};


Player.prototype = {
    constructor: Player,
    listen: function() {
     alert(this.x + " " + this.socket);           // fine get somevalue & [object, object]
     this.socket.on('event', function(data) {
        alert(this.x + " " + this.socket);        // this.x undefined this.socket [object, object]
        $.each(data, function(index,value) { 
           alert(this.x + " " + this.socket);     // undefined undefined  
        });
     });  
    }

return Player;
})();
```

Comment: Well for one thing, what do you expect `this` to refer to in the outer anonymous function context? It will be `window` (the global object) or `undefined` if you're in "strict" mode.

Comment: Coming from Java and C++, you have a vastly different expectation of how `this` behaves.  I've found this to be a great spin-up to how Javascript is different: http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/

Comment: The [JavaScript `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is **very** different from Java's `this`. Also, `x` is not a "variable" but a *property* of your object.

Comment: @Bergi I've got it now. You can call x whatever you like attribute, property, variable depends on the language you are using ...

Comment: @avrono: Not in JS, there's an important distinction between [local] *variable* (in a scope) and *property* /attribute/slot/whatever (on an object).

Comment: @Bergi thanks, I will make sure I get the distinction right.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` in your event and `.each()` callback functions isn't the same `this` where you defined `x` and `socket`. When those callback functions are invoked by the Socket.io library and jQuery (respectively), the value of `this` within those callback functions is usually being provided.

To solve this, your `listen` function should maybe look more like:

```
listen: function() {
 var that = this; // <-- keep a reference to your module
 alert(that.x + " " + that.socket);           // fine get somevalue & [object, object]
 that.socket.on('event', function(data) {
    // in here, this could vary depending on the event
    alert(that.x + " " + that.socket);        // this.x undefined this.socket [object, object]
    $.each(data, function(index,value) { 
       // in here, this = the current data element
       alert(that.x + " " + that.socket);     // undefined undefined  
    });
 });  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Obviously I had not thought that through properly. All makes sense now ...

Comment: @avrono: You're welcome! It's an easy thing to forget about. Just be aware of the fact that `this` can change depending on the context in which it's being used.